# Terraform external data error calling aws cli

Tags: terraform, aws-cli

trying to run a `aws cli` call as a `terraform` `external data` but getting a error for `unmarshal string`

Terraform:

```
data "external" "cognito" {
program = ["sh", "-c", "aws cognito-idp list-user-pool-clients --user-pool-id eu-west-xxx | jq '.UserPoolClients | .[] | select(.ClientName | contains(\"AmazonOpenSearchService\")) | .ClientId'"] 
}
```

running the command directly from bash returns:

```
"123456"
```

Via terraform errors with:

```
│ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
│ 
│ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
│ 
│ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging: https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
│ 
│ Program: /bin/sh
│ Result Error: json: │ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
│ 
│ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
│ 
│ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging: https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
│ 
│ Program: /bin/sh
│ Result Error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]string
```

Comment: Why would you do that, when this exists? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cognito_user_pool_clients

Comment: Hey Mark, no as that sadly brings out 2 lists one for ids and one for names, so i cant filter based on the name (like i am in the aws cli call with jq)

Comment: Got it, yeah that data provider isn't very useful now that I look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running an ad hoc script using the [Terraform external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) you need to return a valid json object (The docs also mention a map of string) which `"123456"` is not. You'd need something such as `'{"clientId":"123456"}'`.

If you want to avoid the script completely, what Mark B suggested in his comment above is the best way to go about it.